# How to use Hls.js with React properly?

Tags: reactjs, hls.js

I am building a react for a video player using Hls.js. I am using React Refs and calling useEffect to get the video element after it is rendard. The issue is I keep getting an error.

```
import Hls from "hls.js";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function VideoPlayer({ data, className = '', ...props }) {
  const videoRef = useRef();

  useEffect(()=>{
    const hls = new Hls({
      "debug": true
    });

    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      hls.log = true;
      hls.loadSource = data.src;
      console.log(videoRef)
      hls.attachMedia(videoRef)
      hls.on(Hls.Events.ERROR, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });

    } else {
      console.log('load')
    }
  },[])

  return (
    <video
      ref={videoRef}
      controls
      {...props}
      src={data.src}
      className={className}
    />
  )
}
```

This is the output I get in the console.

> [log] > Debug logs enabled for "Hls instance" in hls.js version 1.4.9-0.canary.9343

> VideoPlayer.jsx:16 {current: video}current: nullsrc: "blob:[http://192.168.0.205/c68f5827-3d23-4656-9479-c64f7f9b2e51"[[Prototype]]](http://192.168.0.205/c68f5827-3d23-4656-9479-c64f7f9b2e51%22%5B%5BPrototype%5D%5D): Object
> VideoPlayer.jsx:17 [log] > attachMedia
> react-dom.development.js:22839

> Uncaught TypeError: media.addEventListener is not a function
> at BufferController.onMediaAttaching (buffer-controller.ts:181:13)
> at EventEmitter2.emit (index.js:203:33)
> at Hls.emit (hls.ts:288:26)
> at Hls.trigger (hls.ts:296:19)
> at Hls.attachMedia (hls.ts:360:10)
> at VideoPlayer.jsx:17:11
> at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:26)
> at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:13)
> at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:9)
> at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:7)

[Screenshot of Error in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE0qE.png)

Seeing that the Hls.js needs to load after the redering, I used the useEffect but still have an issue.

I have reviewed the other suggestion already and still have the issue.

[How to use hls.js with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904439/how-to-use-hls-js-with-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my mistake. I wasn't grabbing the current ref

```
import Hls from "hls.js";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function VideoPlayer({ data, className = '', ...props }) {
  const videoRef = useRef();

  useEffect(()=>{
    const hls = new Hls({
      "debug": true
    });

    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      hls.log = true;
      hls.loadSource = data.src;
      hls.attachMedia(videoRef.current)
      hls.on(Hls.Events.ERROR, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });

    } else {
      console.log('load')
    }
  },[data])

  return (
    <video
      ref={videoRef}
      controls
      {...props}
      src={data.src}
      className={className}
    />
  )
}
```

I hope this helps anyone else. This was a short post but I was able to figure out after making some coffee...